# how to access private spreadsheet(owned by me & not shared) by other user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have an application (called:leave management) for my company that created from google sites(for UI), google spreadsheet(for Database) and integrated with google apps script. This application handled request for leaving, so, employee that login with company email can read and write the spreadsheet from google sites.
And here's the problem...i don't want the employee could edit the spreadsheet "DIRECT"...they should be write and read on the google sites...so the sharing settings for the spreadsheet must be "PRIVATE"...but it's impossible for read or write by other employee if the spreadsheet was "PRIVATE"...
in my mind...we can access the spreadsheet but we must have email spreadsheet owner, and the password too...it should be like this

```
var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetID", "emailSpreadsheetOwner", "passEmailSpreadsheetOwner")
```

but yeah...it's doesn't work...
could you help me??
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I use the same setup in an app, the spreadsheet is set to 'anyone with the link can edit' but no user knows the name or the ID of the sheet so they can only write and read through the UI and they'll never open the ss itself.
Isn't that what you want ?

Comment: yeah thats what i want...but i'm afraid other employee will know direct link to the spreadsheet :( is it possible to know the direct link for the spreadsheet?

Comment: The ID of the sheet is only visible from the script editor I don't think it's possible for a user to get the ID (but I'm not a 'good' hacker ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of deploying your application. Given your requirements, have your application run as the owner of the script and not as the 'User accessing the web app' 
This way, you (the owner of the script) can keep the spreadsheet private, yet be able to write and read from it when a different user accesses the application.

Comment: yeah its work...but i forget to tell that this application use MailApp.sendEmail...so if i change the application run as the owner of the script and not as the user accessing the web app, the sender from all of sent email was sent by the owner of the script :(

Comment: In which case, you do not have too many choices. Use Serge's method and hope no body will find out the spreadsheet ID.
Otherwise, you can use the advanced options in MailApp.sendEmail so that the email 'appears' to be coming from someone else and not the owner.